# C# windows forms - Getting same thread id for different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am using C# windows forms applicatin. 
I am starting thread by this code

```
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => ThreadFunctions.FirstThread(this));
        thread.Start();
```

How can `main thread` and `thread` have same id ?

I am printing thread id by this code.

`label.Text = "Thread Main ID: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId ;`

also I am starting some tasks, and also getting same Id.

Comment: You can't modify the UI from a non-UI thread, so the code you have will either throw an exception, or you're marshaling to the UI from your other thread.

Comment: Am I missing something? You're printing the ID of the current thread from the main thread, right? So of course it's the same as the main thread...

Comment: You should provide all of the code to get the correct answer.

Comment: I am using invoke, delegate to change UI control value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the threads have the same ID, they are the same thread. My guess is that since the code appears in code to set a label caption it is running on the main thread. You are using `Invoke` to put it on the main thread, aren't you?

Deal with that issue by building the string containing the ID in the thread. That is outside the delegate that is invoked onto the UI thread.

Comment: I think you are right, I am looking variable value by debugger  `int tmp1 = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;`  it is different. but printing in `lable` I am gatting main thread id. How can I print correct id for secondary thread ?

Comment: Like I said. Read the ID in the thread. Use variable capture in your delegate that is invoked. Carry the value of the ID over to the UI thread using that variable capture.